# Flash - Error #2044: Unhandled skinError:. text=Error #2121: Security sandbox violation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a Flash (SWF) file that loads a video skin that is on a different domain and I get the error below:

> Error #2044: Unhandled skinError:. text=Error #2121: Security sandbox
>   violation: Loader.content:
>   ad-dev.somedomain.net/Test2/Select_Expanded_Ad.swf cannot access
>   ad.somedomain.net/ads/i/SkinUnderPlayStopSeekMuteVol.swf. This may be
>   worked around by calling Security.allowDomain.

In the Action Script 3.0 I have:

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://ad.somedomain.net/crossdomain.xml");
Security.allowDomain("*");
MovieClip12.skin="http://ad.somedomain.net/ads/i/SkinUnderPlayStopSeekMuteVol.swf";
```

I have a crossdomain.xml file setup: http://ad.somedomain.net/crossdomain.xml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
   <allow-access-from domain="ad-dev.somedomain.net"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Your cross domain policy URL is incomplete. try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
   <allow-access-from domain="ad-dev.somedomain.net"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: This cross policy xml file should be on the video skin domain. Also try chaning `<allow-access-from domain="ad-dev.somedomain.net"/>` to `<allow-access-from domain="*" />` to check if the specified url is incorrect.

Comment: I have switched it over to an * with the same problem.  Any other ideas?